# USB-C Connector wiring 3 wires

Tags: connector, wiring, usb-c

[image]

Hello,

I am looking for a usb c connector suited for three wires. I can’t find them anywhere. The picture shows the broken connector from a 65w usb c charger. Can anyone tell me where I can get a replacement connector or what they are called?

Thanks in advance.[image][image]

Comment: I assume it's just a regular USB-C connector that has only the power pins wired to it and none of the data pins.

Comment: All usb c connectors are suitable for this. You're looking for the custom pcb. Which is harder to find. You need a USB-C breakout board.

Comment: there muist be an IC on the back of that PCB to handfe the power negotioation. "USB Power delivery" is not possible over three conductors

Comment: I added a couple more pictures. I don’t see an IC anywhere. Does someone know where I can get a connector like this?

Comment: Can you use something that's different? https://www.adafruit.com/product/4396  This (or similar) breakout board should at least be able to get you going in pinch. I'm guessing there is something expensive hard-wired to the other end of that cable? Otherwise, any USB-C 3.1 or better cable should replace that one without a problem.

Comment: Hello I had the same problem, I bought a new connector on aliexpress and soldered it to the original charger. Follow the link:
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mPBPdTE

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, I can tell you what I've learned.
The 3 wires are Vbus, GND, and CC1.  From the picture it looks like the blue wire is CC1.  Can't tell what the other wires are, going to need to test them.  They should default to 5v, which should allow you to test polarity.

USB Power Delivery (PD) is a single-wire protocol which communicates over CC1.

What I'm going to do to repair my charger is use a USB 2  type C male connector. The one that has V D+ D- G solder pads, plus 5.1k resistors. My plan is to remove the resistors, which is pull-down between CC and GND.  Exposing CC1.
When I finish doing this and it works. I will update with pictures showing connection of USB C connector.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with pics?